# How many times can we use EOF?

Tags: php

I was used `EOF` for print html code in PHP . for example :

```
echo <<<EOF
    Hello World!
EOF;
```

What volume of output can be used for `eof`? 
How many times can we use `EOF`?

Comment: I don't quite understand what your question is, but you can use heredoc as many times as you want

Comment: You can add any volume of code to heredoc and output it as much as you want. [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technical name for this syntax is [Heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

The PHP documentation doesn't specify a maximum length of content, however you would foolish to use it for very large amounts of text/HTML etc. as it makes your code unreadable and harder to maintain.

Example: If you have an HTML page which needs some customisation, far better to code the whole thing as a normal HTML file and add `<?php echo "Hello World!"; ?>` in the appropriate place. (This is how *views* in model-view-controller (MVC) work.)

You can use heredoc multiple times and with an identifier other than `EOF`.